# Do spring and autumn last as long as summer and winter?

Tags: game-of-thrones, a-song-of-ice-and-fire

Westeros's climates is ruled by random-length winter and summer. It is said that summer and winter's lengths are correlated: the longer the summer, the longer the winter. But what about spring and autumn? Do spring and autumn last as long as summer and winter?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**TLDR:**
There are at least two notable examples of long summer followed by a much shorter autumn.

**Long answer:**

As stated before, there are at least two notable examples of long summer followed by a much shorter autumn:

- The summer during the reign of Maekar was quite long (seven years), and so the winter (unknow length but hardly suggested to be quite long). However, the autumn was short.

  A Game of Thrones - Eddard V

  > The heavy jeweled chain around the old man's neck chinked softly as he shifted in his seat. "To be sure, King Maekar's summer was hotter than this one, and near as long. There were fools, even in the Citadel, who took that to mean that the Great Summer had come at last, the summer that never ends, but in the seventh year it broke suddenly, and we had a short autumn and a terrible long winter".
- The current events: At the beginning of the story(around 298 AC), we are on a long summer. The summer ends in 299AC,in the prologue of ACOK, after ten years, two turns(month), and sixteen days. The winter comes in 300AC, during the epilogue of ADWD. Even if we don't know the exact time lapse between the two, it is much more shorter than the summer.

  A Clash of Kings - Prologue

  > Shireen gave a brave little nod. "Mother said the white raven means it's not summer anymore."
  >   "That is so, my lady. The white ravens fly only from the Citadel." Cressen's fingers went to the chain about his neck, each link forged from a different metal, each symbolizing his mastery of another branch of learning; the maester's collar, mark of his order. In the pride of his youth, he had worn it easily, but now it seemed heavy to him, the metal cold against his skin. "They are larger than other ravens, and more clever, bred to carry only the most important messages. This one came to tell us that the Conclave has met, considered the reports and measurements made by maesters all over the realm, and declared this great summer done at last. Ten years, two turns, and sixteen days it lasted, the longest summer in living memory."

  A Dance with Dragons - Epilogue

  > Not silver. White. The bird is white.
  >   The white ravens of the Citadel did not carry messages, as their dark cousins did. When they went forth from Oldtown, it was for one purpose only: to herald a change of seasons.
  >   "Winter," said Ser Kevan. The word made a white mist in the air. He turned away from the window.

Comment: The autumn in Maekar's reign that you quote is apparently 230 AC/231 AC but I couldn't track the sources down. There's a spring from 209 AC - 210 AC but again I couldn't track the sources down for it.